# Is there a passive mechanical reverse centrifugal clutch?

Tags: mechanical-engineering

Is there a passive mechanical *reverse* centrifugal clutch, one that only engages *below* a certain rotation speed?

Comment: Yes. Just reverse the role/linkages of the springs and weights Make the springs clamp the clutch and the weights overcome the spring to release. Need a way to release so you can start it up though or else catch-22

Comment: Isn't that how ICE car starter motors work?

Comment: @CarlWitthoft Don't know but that could be a one way bearing.

Comment: Car starters use a Bendix gear, as far as I know.

Comment: @Transistor starters use or used inertia with a gear to throw the drive gear at the ring gear while turning slowly, the other method engages the drive gear using the solenoid and a lever arm or fork which then operated the contacts for full power at yhe end of the travel. The second had a "clutch" using an inclined ramp to allow drive but prevent the engine iverspeeding yhe starter.

Answer (score 1):

It may not be exactly what you were looking for but the Idea could be useful.

Almost all cordless window shades could be modified to do what you need.

They have weighted (not spring-loaded) pawls that due to centripetal force release the clutch at a certain slow speed allowing the shade to roll but locks if you stop.